# clump array values into groups

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

im trying to convert a png file into rgba values using this code

```
import sys
import numpy as np

# get infile as argument
infile = sys.argv[1]

# load png

img=Image.open(infile)
pixels = img.load()

#build array

pix_val_flat = [v for c in [[x,y] for x in range(img.size[0]) for y in range(img.size[1])] for v in pixels[c[0],c[1]]]

print(pix_val_flat)
```

with this code im getting a array output like this:

**255, 255, 255, 15, 211, 211, 211, 29, 128, 126, 119, 107**

how could i modify this code to give me a array output with one entire pixel per array entry?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your `pix_val_flat` list - you can group them together into groups of 4

`pix_val_grouped = [(pix_val_flat[idx:idx+4]) for idx in range(len(lst)) if idx % 4 == 0]`